# How to increase transparency of logo and navbar on scroll down?

Tags: html, css

I want to increase the transparency of the image and top menu after I scroll and the logo in the header changes to small. Can anyone help?
Here is the site url: https://theportwebdesign.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The et-fixed-header class is appended to #top-header when your scroll. I assume a JS script is taking care of this.

To change the opacity add this line to your CSS or modifying existing. You should probably be able to change this is your theme settings somewhere, if not you are most likely going to have to use !important as it looks like most of your CSS is written directly to the screen.

```
.et-fixed-header#main-header{
     background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8) !important;
}
```

The first three numbers are used for color and the last is used for opacity.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response Orlando. I had missed the  et-fixed-header class. Thanks again!

Comment: @Rohan no problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the color value of header (div) from RGB to RGBA onscroll event

```
<div id="logo" style='width:1024px;height:50px;'></div>

<script>
 document.getElementById("logo").addEventListener("scroll", modifyHeader);
 function modifyHeader()
 {
    document.getElementById('logo').style.backgroundColor="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3)"; // This is RGBA color value which makes your div transparent
 }
</script>
```